# WKWebView not able to recognize the text returned by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, swift, wkwebview

I am using a WKWebView in my iOS app to display an HTML string. Now I need to let my app capture the word being tapped in the HTML page. I have a piece of jQuery code embedded in the HTML to capture the word and then redirect the page to a fake URL including this word. And in the WKWebView's WKNavigationDelegate method "decidePolicyFor", I parse the requested URL to retrieve the word. Everything works well except that the word itself is gone. I tried the same HTML page on Safari and the redirecting URL is totally correct which I can confirm in the URL address. I don't know what's wrong between the jQuery code and WKWebView. Any advice would be most appreciated.

My HTML string:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                              var p = $('p');

                              p.click(function(e) {
                                      var sel_obj = window.getSelection(); //it will return an object
                                      sel_obj.modify("move","forward","character");
                                      sel_obj.modify("extend","backward","word");

                                      sel_obj.modify("move","backward","character");
                                      sel_obj.modify("extend","forward","word");

                                      var text = sel_obj.toString().trim();
                                      text = text.toLowerCase();
                                      window.location = "https://www.anonexistent.com/wordclicked/" + text;
                                      });

                              });
            </script>
    </header>

    <body>
        <h1>CLICK-TO-PICK-THE-WORD</h1>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p><font size=20>Baa Baa Black Sheep<font></p>
    </body>
</html>
```

My iOS code (in Swift):

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

    let redirectURLString = navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString ?? ""
    print("redirectURLString: \(redirectURLString)")

    if redirectURLString == "about:blank" {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)
    }
    else {
        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.cancel)
    }
}
```

Now the page is showing correctly. And when I tap the word "Sheep" in the paragraph, jQuery can recognize the word and construct the redirecting URL as

```
https://www.anonexistent.com/wordclicked/sheep
```

which I have verified on Safari. The problem is that in Xcode, navigationAction.request.url?.absoluteString is only

```
https://www.anonexistent.com/wordclicked/
```

and the word "sheep" is missing.